# How can 22 cynical soul effect basketball player on Earth?

Tags: soul-2020

Here we can see 22 cynical soul, who is at "Great Before" throws snow
and basketball player fails to score a point:

[image]

How can 22 cynical soul effect basketball player on Earth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the entire point of 22’s exercise, of which this is one example,  to show that Souls can impact mortals on earth.

Chalk it up to Souls can impact mortals on earth because Souls can impact mortals on earth.